# (Yet) Another java rebus

Tags: rebus

Consider the following `Java` program:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[][] matrix = new Object[][]{{0,8,4,3,2},{3,4,0,4,2},{1,2,new Exception(),5,2},{2,1,2,9,3},{1,2,0,6,5}};
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(matrix[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

What phrase is this referencing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it:

> "There's a glitch in the matrix" or something close to that?
>  There's a few one liners with small variations but the one that rings a bell is when they're walking up the stairs and see the same black cat twice.

Comment: Would that actually throw the exception though? Pretty sure it'd crash with an illegalMatrix something or other error which adds a second layer of hint as the matrix in the code has multiple glitches. @AMACB

Comment: It doesn't throw the exception, but if you run it, it will print a matrix and in the middle you have a `"java.lang.Exception"`.

Comment: Yah. Figured it'd throw some other exception. @Gendarme thanks for clarification. Not at a comp to run it.